# PHP populate the data from database when District is selected

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database

please follow this post instead Check my following post please
 [Chained multiple selects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712199/chained-multiple-selects)

I have this code where a user selects the particular category of doctor and then the District in which he wants to look it. After state he needs to click the station(in the selected district) 
Doctor >> District >> Station

```
Here is the code 
<html>
<body>
<form action="process.php" method="post">
<select name="cat">
<?php
$sql="select distinct Category from doctors order by Category asc";
$query=mysql_query($sql);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo "<option value='{$row[Category]}'>{$row[Category]}</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<select name="station">
<?php
$sql_1="select distinct Station from doctors order by Station asc";
$query_1=mysql_query($sql_1);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_1))
{

echo "<option value=".$row[Station].">".$row[Station]."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<input name="C" type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Process.php

```
$mySqlStm ="SELECT Name FROM doctors WHERE Category='$myValue' and Station='$myStation'";

$result2 = mysql_query($mySqlStm) or die("Error:mysql_error()"); 

if(mysql_num_rows($result2) == 0){ 
echo("<br/>no records found"); 
} 
ELSE 
{ 
echo "<table border='1'>"; 

//ECHO THE RECORDS FETCHED
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
{ 
echo "<tr>"; 
//echo "<td>" . $row['Station'] . "</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>" ; 
//echo "<td>" . $row['Phone 1'] . "</td>"; 
//echo "<td>" . $row['Mobile'] . "</td>"; 

}
```

I want the station category to be auto filled when district is selected and When a category of doctor is selected, the district has to be auto filled.

How can I do it? I would prefer Javascript because I know a little bit about it. 
Also, i have all the data in one database it looks like this

Category | Station | District | Name | Qualification and so on

Comment: You can use ajax for your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Ajax + jQuery will do that for you in a few lines of code.

Tutorial here: [Ajax+jQuery Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Ajax for the state and city

From this you can get the idea for the doctor list

[Please check it once this is good example](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/01/populate-triple-drop-down-list-change-options-value-from-database-using-ajax-and-php.html)

Answer (score 0):

Demo for Country, State and City is [here](http://www.vinaykumard.co.cc)

Code is [Here](https://github.com/vinaykumard/Dynamic-Dropdown-)

Customize it your way..

You can change the code in findCity.php to Process.php and in js/location.js
you have:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "findCity.php",
    data: strURL,
    cache: false,
    success: function(d){
    $('#citydiv').show().html(d);
    }
});
```

`#citydiv` is the part which will be changed to the result you got in Process.php